# I need to make table a little bit interactive

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here I found this on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kbmNu/), and it works on Jsfiddle,  but when I try it to make in simple html doesnt work anything, except pure html table
This is what I include into my html, I think that is all, but something is not Ok. Does any one know anything about this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: include jQuery before bootstrap.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```